# Value incorrectly showing list

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to make a list of cogs that have been loaded however the title "Cogs Loaded" is showing for each cog. I'm wanting to achieve a list with just one title.

Here is my code:

```
async def cogs(self, ctx):
    """
    Lists the cogs that have been loaded.
    """
    colour = ctx.author.colour if hasattr(ctx.author, 'colour') else discord.Colour.blurple()
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=colour)
    for cog in self.bot.cogs:
        if cog in self.bot.cogs:
            embed.add_field(name="**Cogs Loaded**", value=cog)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Help appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `embed = discord.Embed(colour=colour, title="**Cogs Loaded**")`

Comment: I could do that but the `name=` value needs a required field so it can't be empty.

Comment: Well what do you want the little boxes to display about the cogs

Comment: The value `name="Cogs Loaded"`to be displayed once with the value `value=cogs` as a list .

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own answer

```
async def cogs(self, ctx):
    """
    Show the cogs that have been loaded.
    """
    colour = ctx.author.colour if hasattr(ctx.author, 'colour') else discord.Colour.blurple()
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=colour, title="**Cogs Loaded**")
    cogs_list = self.bot.cogs
    loaded = [f"**{cog}**" for cog in cogs_list]
    embed.add_field(name="Cogs:", value="\n".join(loaded))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```